# Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/addon.xm

Tags: android, sdk

I tried to ran sdk 32 BIT for andriod in windows 7 and I got error message
Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/addon.xm **reason: Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com**
Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/addon.xml **reason: Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com**

I read some web that explain that I need to update the  HTTP prxoy server
I tried several options but it didn't work.

Do I need to do any change in IE9 ?

What should be the HTTP proxy sever ?

Do you know how i can solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue before. You can download a zip file of the components you need and manually install them in Eclipse. Follow this link - 
https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

I know that this applies to Android Studio and not Eclipse, but in case someone stumbles across it:

I got the solution for the Android Studio installation after trying everything that I could find on the Internet. If you're using Android Studio and getting this error:

Find `[Path_to_Android_SDK]\sdk\tools\android.bat`.
In my case, it was in `C:\Users\Nathan\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools\android.bat`.

Right-click it, hit `Edit`, and scroll all the way down to the bottom.

Find where it says: `call %java_exe% %REMOTE_DEBUG% ...`

Replace that with `call %java_exe% -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true %REMOTE_DEBUG% ...`

Restart Android Studio/SDK and everything works. This fixed many issues for me, including being unable to fetch XML files or create new projects.