# Some sites could not be found, when I tried to update the installation software

Tags: java, android

I have face problem in eclipse:

Below is my problem:

Some sites could not be found.  See the error log for more detail.
No repository found at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/site.xml.

No repository found at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r23.0.5-windows.zip.

Comment: Have you tried the path till here :https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository

Comment: yes i have tried...but i have face this problem: Could not find http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository

Comment: Hope this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796780/failed-to-fetch-url-http-dl-ssl-google-com-android-eclipse-addon-xm

Comment: I have updated ADT with 23.0.4, but sdk contains rev. 24.0.2, so there is a confliction between 23.0.4 and 24.0.2. In sdk 23.0.4 does not shows for update after rev.22 direct 24.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution: I have find the solution for that, install "Android Studio 1.0.1" from developers site "http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html". It should automatically install 24.0.2.

1) There was a bug in SDK Tools 24.0.0 which makes the SDK Manager not work on some 32-bit Windows systems. When you start Android Studio 1.0.1 you get a balloon saying that Tools 24.0.1 is available; click on it, and then you can install it right from within the IDE (that doesn't use the SDK Manager to do the install). SDK Manager should now work again. If not you can download a fix for the SDK manager directly from 
http://tools.android.com/knownissues

2) I also met this issue after updated Android SDK Tools, the find_java.bat file in your SDK Dir\tools\lib PATH has a small problem.

Please replace the code in line33: %sys_32%\find /i "x86" > NUL && set arch_ext=32 || set arch_ext=64 to %sys_32%\find /i "x86" > NUL && (set arch_ext=32) || (set arch_ext=64) and save it. Restart android.bat in your SDK Dir\tools PATH. It will run normally!!!

BTW, the newest Android SDK Tools(24.0.2) has repaired this issue!